# Nginx Returning 504 Error

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I'm getting a 504 error from Nginx on my Ubuntu server where I'm running Rails using Unicorn.

When I look in the Nginx error.log.1, I see:

`2014/01/21 18:06:02 [error] 698#0: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream...`

When I tried to look in the Rails production.log, the server returned `Killed`  When I tried to restart Unicorn, I got `master failed to start, check stderr log for details`

When I run `df -h` I get:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda         20G  4.1G   15G  22% /
```

When I run `df -i` I get:

```
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/vda       1310720 144242 1166478   12% /
```

I tried to delete the `production.log` file and restart Nginx and Unicorn.  I can now restart Unicorn, but I'm still getting the 504 error.

I also see this in the Nginx error.log:

```
2014/02/09 05:44:55 [error] 2245#0: *23 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 73.187.444.220, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/favicon.ico", host: "foo.com"
```

Please help!

Comment: How much memory don't you have?

Comment: I have 15G available

Comment: He's talking about RAM. You've already quoted your diskspace. As for the problem, it seems to be with unicorn rather than nginx. Nginx is simply returning the 504 because it can't connect to your unicorn process properly (i take it you've misconfigured stuff but you haven't included much info on it).